# Implementing Midpoint Displacement

Tags: c++, algorithm, directx

I have been able to successfully implement midpoint displacement in a numbered array in another program and so i'v tried to implement it in a 3D world to create terrain however the outcome of the algorithm isn't what i expected.

```
void MidPointDisplacement(float grid[][WIDTH], int left, int right, int top, int bottom, int row, int col)
{
  int centreX = (left + right) / 2;     //Get the centre of the row
  int centreY = (top + bottom) / 2;     //Get the centre of the column

  if (centreX == left)
  {
    return;
  }
  if (centreY == bottom)
  {
    return;
  }

  grid[top][centreX] = ((grid[top][left] + grid[top][right]) / 2) + jitter;     //define top
  grid[bottom][centreX] = ((grid[bottom][left] + grid[bottom][right]) / 2) + jitter; //define bottom
  grid[centreY][left] = ((grid[top][left] + grid[bottom][left]) / 2) + jitter; //define left
  grid[centreY][right] = ((grid[top][right] + grid[bottom][right]) / 2) + jitter;  //define right

  grid[centreX][centreY] = ((grid[centreY][left] + grid[centreY][right] +     grid[top][centreX] + grid[bottom][centreX]) / 4) + jitter; //Get centre

 //decreased the random values
 RANDMAX / 2;
 RANDMIN / 2;

 MidPointDisplacement(grid, centreX, right, centreY, bottom, row, col);
 MidPointDisplacement(grid, left, centreX, top, centreY, row, col);
 MidPointDisplacement(grid, centreX, right, top, centreY, row, col);
 MidPointDisplacement(grid, left, centreX, centreY, bottom, row, col);
}
```

The result of the above is this:
[3D Midpoint Displacement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfEUp.png)

However I expected a terrain like this:

[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0taeZ.png)

Is there any reason why this maybe? I initially thought it could've been the jitter however decreasing the initial value doesn't solve this problem.

```
float jitter = rand() % (int)(RANDMAX - RANDMIN + 1) + RANDMIN;
```

Jitter is a global float that takes a random value between RANDMAX (initial value of 5.0f) and RANDMIN (initial value of -5.0f).

Solution:

To fix the above error I deleted the jitter I had created in the program and instead made jitter a float variable of 1.

In the MidpointDisplacement function I changed this:

```
  grid[top][centreX] = ((grid[top][left] + grid[top][right]) / 2) + jitter;     //define top
  grid[bottom][centreX] = ((grid[bottom][left] + grid[bottom][right]) / 2) + jitter; //define bottom
  grid[centreY][left] = ((grid[top][left] + grid[bottom][left]) / 2) + jitter; //define left
  grid[centreY][right] = ((grid[top][right] + grid[bottom][right]) / 2) + jitter;  //define right

  grid[centreX][centreY] = ((grid[centreY][left] + grid[centreY][right] +     grid[top][centreX] + grid[bottom][centreX]) / 4) + jitter; //Get centre
```

To this:

```
  grid[top][centreX] = ((grid[top][left] + grid[top][right]) / 2) + ((rand() % 256) - 128) / 128.0F * JITTER_RANGE * jitter;  //define top
  grid[bottom][centreX] = ((grid[bottom][left] + grid[bottom][right]) / 2) + ((rand() % 256) - 128) / 128.0F * JITTER_RANGE * jitter; //define bottom
  grid[centreY][left] = ((grid[top][left] + grid[bottom][left]) / 2) + ((rand() % 256) - 128) / 128.0F * JITTER_RANGE * jitter; //define left
  grid[centreY][right] = ((grid[top][right] + grid[bottom][right]) / 2) + ((rand() % 256) - 128) / 128.0F * JITTER_RANGE * jitter;  //define right

  grid[centreY][centreX] = ((grid[centreY][left] + grid[centreY][right] + grid[top][centreX] + grid[bottom][centreX]) / 4) + ((rand() % 256) - 128) / 128.0F * JITTER_RANGE * jitter; //Get centre
```

I then called the function again as done before however this time I divided the jitter by 2.

Also, I discovered that I stupidly had centreX and centreY the wrong way around in the line(Not changed here):

```
  grid[centreX][centreY] = ((grid[centreY][left] + grid[centreY][right] +     grid[top][centreX] + grid[bottom][centreX]) / 4) + jitter; //Get centre
```

Comment: What is `jitter` and what is `RANDMAX / 2` AND `RANDMIN / 2` supposed to do?

Comment: @GuyRT Added declaration of jitter to question

Comment: That definition of `jitter` doesn't really make sense. As you've described it, it won't change. I think you need a function taking `RANDMIN` and `RANDMAX` as arguments. Also to make the recursion work, you need to pass `RANDMIN` and `RANDMAX` to `MidPointDisplacement`

Comment: @GuyRT I have now passed the jitter into the function and halfed it before I call the function again however the terrain still seems to be jaggered

Comment: Solution in question. Thanks to @GuyRT for pointing out error.